# How to set customized pretty URLs in Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I want to show pretty URLs for my posts like year/month/title and don't want to show the id or controller name.

How can I do this in Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem which lets you set another attribute than id to resolve models into URLs and vice versa.

Using this gem to generate user URLs by nick:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
end

User.create! name: "Joe Schmoe"

GET http://localhost:3000/users/joe-schmoe
```